# How to build an array of dictionaries depending on the values of a certain model

Tags: swift, model, url-parameters, type-alias

I have a type alias of `[String:Any]`

```
public typealias Parameters = [String:Any]
```

And i have a computed property that will build these parameters from the model values.

```
var parameters: Parameters {
    switch self {
    case .addOFFProduct(let product):
        var parameters: Parameters!
        let code = product.code!
        let username = product.username
        let password = product.password
        if let productName = product.productName, let genericName = product.genericName, let countriesText = product.countriesText, let brandsText = product.brandsText, let storesText = product.storesText, let ingredientText = product.ingredientText, let quantity = product.quantity, let additivesText = product.additivesText, let categoriesText = product.categoriesText {
            parameters = [
                Constants.OffProduct.code:        code,
                Constants.username:               username,
                Constants.password:               password,
                Constants.OffProduct.productName: productName,
                Constants.OffProduct.genericName: genericName
            ]
        }
        return parameters
    }
}
```

Now I need to build the parameters type according to the production values if they are nil then it won't be added in the `[String:Any]`.
For example, if `generic name` is `nil` and all others are not then the parameters will be like follows

```
parameters = [
    Constants.OffProduct.code:        code,
    Constants.username:               username,
    Constants.password:               password,
    Constants.OffProduct.productName: productName
    //GENERIC NAME REMOVED
]
```

How can I achieve a logic likes this. Im confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every item do like this

```
if genericName != nil {
    parameters.updateValue(genericName,forKey:Constants.OffProduct.genericName)
}
```

//

create 2 array one for constants and the other for values that my be nil

```
let arrValues = [product.genericName, product.productName,,,,,,,,]
let keysArr = [Constants.OffProduct.genericName, Constants.OffProduct.productName,,,,,,,]

(0..<arrValues.count).forEach {

    if let value = arrValues[$0] {

      parameters[keysArr[$0]] = value 

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow didn't know about `updateValue` thats awesome will test now

Comment: 1. `genericName` can't be `nil` since it was created with `if let`. 2. What's the point of `updateValue` here? The goal isn't to update the value, the goal is to only add it if the value isn't `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy for sure he'll remove the if let , Do you think i meant this inside if letsssss ? , updateValue like [] create if not exists it's not a problem to use anyone

Comment: I think i will need to create the `var parameters = [ ]` first with the non optional values then add the others from `forEach` right

Comment: yes declare it that , it'll be dynamically changed inside the **forEach**